# How can i use Descarta2D package for Mathematica?

Tags: geometry, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, analytical

Recently I download a pdf book named -"Exploring Analytical Geometry with Mathematica ".In this book, they used a package  "Descarta2D". I can't understand how can I add these packages in my Mathematica.

I look at many websites to solve this problem but I can't run the code of this book yet.
some links that i visited -
1.[wolfram comunity](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2229803)
2.[wolfram comunity](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1908985)
3.[wolfram comunity](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Nov/msg00437.html)

I want to add these packages in Mathematica and run the all code of the book-Exploring Analytical Geometry with Mathematica.

book link-
[Exploring Analytical Geometry with Mathematica](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/157/ExploringAnalyticGeometrywithMathematica.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are supposed to copy the Descarta packages to `$BaseDirectory\Applications`, which on my system corresponds to `C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications`.  Then when you try to use a Descarta notebook automatic initialisation should be able to find the packages to load.

[image]

By the way, the last valid Descarta2d site archive was Sept 2019

https://web.archive.org/web/20190915151048/http://descarta2d.com/

[image]

From the author

https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/c/uNwV45TmthU/m/_LbKZEjmjcQJ

> **The complete Mathematica source code for all the Descarta2D notebooks
> is published in the free PDF file of the textbook** (in Part VII,
> Packages). The Mathematica source code for all the exercise answers is
> provided in the free PDF file as well (in Part VIII, Explorations).
>
> Alternatively, it is a significant time-saver to have the option to
> purchase and download the notebook files directly, rather than cutting
> them from the book's PDF file using Acrobat and pasting them into
> Mathematica.

https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/c/u235VmaVt04/m/q2LwSJXMheQJ

> The Mathematica add-on package, Descarta2D, has been certified to be
> compatible with Mathematica Version 8 (previously certified for
> Versions 3-7). The entire textbook "Exploring Analytic Geometry with
> Mathematica" (including the user manual for Descarta2D) is available
> for free viewing and download at www.Descarta2D .com (both PDF and on-
> line versions, 865 pages, ~3Mb, are available).
>
> The corresponding
> Descarta2D Mathematica notebooks are available for purchase at the
> same web site (the notebooks are not required to read/ study the
> textbook, but they are needed to re-run the sample problems or to use
> Descarta2D for applications beyond the samples).

Uncertain whether the code in the PDF from 2019 is updated to version 8.  Maybe just the paid addons.